# How to define the height of a div in percentage relative to a container with a dynamic height?

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

I have some simple html like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="box1"><img src="images1.png" width="100%" /></div>
<div id="box2">Some text</div>
<div id="box3"><img src="image2.png" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
```

The container is supposed to cover the entire page. I would like box2 to be 20% of the height of the container. The tricky part is that the height of the images in box1 and box3 are relative to the width of the viewport and makes the container larger than the browser window.

If I simply set box2's height in percentage in the stylesheet, the height will be defined as 20% of the height of the viewport, not 20% of the height of the container.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set position:relative to the container?

Comment: Please post the CSS code you have tried as well. Also providing an online example would be great.

Comment: Ok, I've made a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/oyat0fud/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution to my problem: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/oyat0fud/6)

```
body, html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}  
#container{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
#overlay{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
border: 1px solid red;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#box1{
width: 100%;
}
#box2{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
#box3{
width: 100%;
}

<div id="container">
<div id="box1"><img src="image_40pct.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
<div id="box2"><img src="image_20pct.jpg" width="100%" />
  <div id="overlay">This text is shown above the image.</div>
</div>
<div id="box3"><img src="image_40pct.jpg" width="100%" /></div>
</div>
```

As I know the sizes of the images in box1 and box3, I can just place an image in box2 with a height that corresponds to 20% of the total height of the three images combined. I then use "position:absolute" and z-index to place a div on top of that image with the height set to 100%. Mission accomplished :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1afcbrt/), maybe you can achieve the 20% of the height by using margins:

```
#box2{
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

This way you'll have 10% on top and 10% on bottom, for a total of 20%.

Comment: Interesting idea but that won't make the container 20% of the height.  It is, literally, just 20% margin.  Any inner content to .box2 will increase the height to beyond 20%.  Taking your idea but adjusting it to give .box2 `padding-top:10%;` `padding-bottom:10%;` and `position:relative;` and then place an inner container with 100% width/height and overflow hidden and absolute position, would give a static sized 20% height, 100% width container at the cost of non-dynamic height scaling. Depends on the design goal, I guess. Fiddle Update: http://jsfiddle.net/L1afcbrt/1/

Comment: @jmbertucci right, i didn't consider the case with a big block of text.. Still the text will be partially hidden if it passes the 20% limit. In that case you might want to allow vertical scrolling as you can see in this other Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwgojvL8/

Comment: Good comment. I should have more explicitly mentioned that.  Also, I don't know why but we might as well just set height to 20% instead of playing with padding or margins. :)

Comment: I need to be able to fill the entire box with text, so achieving the correct size using padding and/or margin won't work. See also my example on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oyat0fud/5/